# Fancybox2: changing both overlay background color and padding around image

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm a total JS noob - I tried to modify my Fancybox2 installation following the tipps on the fancybox site, but I can't get it to work. What I want is 1. a white overlay instead of a black one, appr 70% opacity and 2. a reduced padding (2px instead of the default 15).
I was redirected to JSFiddle and I can change the code there for each of the two issues separately - but I cannot combine both. And: I don't know where to paste that code. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

This did the trick for changing the padding:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    padding: 2
});
```

and this worked for the background color:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However, I don't know how to combine and where to put that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    padding: 2,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks - and can you tell me where to put this code?